# Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds

Tags: centos, yum

readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm FAILED
http://mirror.verinomi.com/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://mirror.verinomi.com/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')

I got an error while updating yum.
yum update

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
time wget http://mirror.verinomi.com/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

- 

```
time wget http://mirror.verinomi.com/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
--2022-08-25 11:24:31--  http://mirror.verinomi.com/centos/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
Resolving mirror.verinomi.com (mirror.verinomi.com)... 193.162.43.250
Connecting to mirror.verinomi.com (mirror.verinomi.com)|193.162.43.250|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 197696 (193K) [application/x-rpm]
Saving to: ‘readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm’

>

readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm            100%[=====================================================================================>] 193,06K   555KB/s    in 0,3s

2022-08-25 11:24:32 (555 KB/s) - ‘readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm’ saved [197696/197696]


real    0m0,758s
user    0m0,010s
sys     0m0,009s
```

If there is a big delay check your internet connection. If your internet speed is really low (like downloading "Less than 1000 bytes/sec the last 30 seconds") it will stop the update through this mirror and may try another.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the timeout of pacman with the parameter --disable-download-timeout. Then you should be able to download, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

added "`timeout=300`" to `/etc/yum.conf` and updates were successful